# Circle CI with Detox build for iOS (xcodebuild) command fails

Tags: xcode, react-native, circleci, xcodebuild, detox

We are using a Circle CI machine runner on a Macbook Pro to run our Circle CI pipeline to test and build our React Native iOS build. Everything is working fine up until our detox build, which issues this `xcodebuild` command:

```
xcodebuild -workspace ios/MyProduct.xcworkspace -UseNewBuildSystem=YES -scheme MyProduct_Dev -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator clean build
```

The error is as follows:

```
error: Multiple commands produce '/var/opt/circleci/workdir/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyProduct.app/Frameworks/hermes.framework'
    note: Target 'MyProduct' (project 'MyProduct') has copy command from '/var/opt/circleci/workdir/ios/Pods/hermes-engine/destroot/Library/Frameworks/universal/hermes.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator/hermes.framework' to '/var/opt/circleci/workdir/ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyProduct.app/Frameworks/hermes.framework'
    note: That command depends on command in Target 'MyProduct' (project 'MyProduct'): script phase “[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks”
```

If I run the command on my own development machine, it works.

I did run this manually on the build machine and ran into this, but I removed the offending line in the "Build Phases" within xcode, and then was able to build it by running the command manually on the command line. Seeing as the above error occurs of course in a non-GUI environment, I'm not sure how I can target or remove that line specifically, or find where it is coming from. It is not in my `xcproj` source code.

I've tried a lot of stuff, deintegrating the pods, cleaning the build folder, no idea how this build command is different than when I run it manually on my machine or the host machine, because as I said, when I run this identical `xcodebuild` command in the terminal of the host machine, the build succeeds.

Any ideas or tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Update: getting the same now for even a normal fastlane build i.e. `fastlane ios beta`